# (slick slide) slider with dynamic first slide

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I have a page with a bunch of images on it. And I have slick slider with those images. No matter what image I click on, I always see first image as first slide.

structure:

```
#slick-slider
  .slider-for
    .div
      .image{id='<%= @product.id %>'}
    .div
      .image{id='<%= @product.id %>'}
    .div
      .image{id='<%= @product.id %>'}

  .slider-nav
    .div
      .image{id='<%= @product.id %>'}
    .div
      .image{id='<%= @product.id %>'}
    .div
      .image{id='<%= @product.id %>'}
```

I've tried:

```
$('.slider-for').slick('slickGoTo', $("[id=<%= @product.id %>]"));
```

I need to go to the image in slider that I clicked on.

Will appreciate any help.
Alex.

## UPD:

A little more details:
After click on image, slider opens in modal window.
Assuming every "image" block has it's unique id, how do I care certain id to script?

```
.image{id='x'}

$('.slider-for').slick('slickGoTo', $("[id=<%= x %>]"));
```

this is not working.

Comment: Looks like you're using the same id in every image... maybe this is causing the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse! Not really, Id is defined by loop, so every 'image' block has unique id.